# awesomium open clicked linked in user's browser

Tags: browser, anchor, awesomium

I have a windows forms application that has Awesomium browser control in it.
I want if the loaded page in awesomium contains a link, to open it in the user's default browser (chrome, ff, ie...) when the user clicks it insread of loading inside awesomium itself.

Much thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution.

handle the URL click from your user at client side (JS).
Let JS call a AWESOMIUM C# function and pass the URL clicked.

In the C# do:

```
string url = args.Arguments[0];
Process.Start(url);
```

Hope this helps someone